# pyttsx3.init() give an error in python 3.9

Tags: python-3.x

I tried below code:

```
>>> import pyttsx3
>>> engine = pyttsx3.init()
>>> engine.say('hello')
>>> engine.runAndWait()
```

But it give me an error as below:

```
import pywintypes
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywintypes'
```

**I already tried this to solve:**

```
pip install pypiwin32
python -m pip install pywin32
pip install -U pypiwin32
python -m pip install pyttsx3==2.71
```

But not any one work for me.
I'm using win10
can anyone help me?

Comment: try conda. It's maybe one installer that able to set env properly

Comment: I confirm your issue though having python installed from https://www.python.org/ on win10

Comment: pip uninstall pypiwin32
pip install pypiwin32

This helped me this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use pyttsx3 in python 3 you have to use pip3 not pip to install the packages. It won't work with pip. pip works for python2 only.

Try the following:

```
pip3 install pywin32 pypiwin32 pyttsx3
```

This should work

Comment: C:\Users\Asus>pip --version
pip 20.2.4 from c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python - works fine. C:\Users\Asus>pip3 --version
pip 20.2.4 from c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)